# Reading a List<string>[] into a dynamic labels

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string, list

I'm having troubles trying to read data from a `List<string[]>` into a dynamic label.

Here is the code:

```
private void CuentasDeUsuarioForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List <string> [] cuentas = db.Select("SELECT * FROM cuentas_de_usuario");
            foreach(List<string> acc in cuentas)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < acc.Count; i++)
                {
                    Label nuevoLabelCuenta = new Label { Text = acc[i] };
                }
            }
        }
```

Anyone knows where i am doing it wrong? I didnt get any syntaxy or compile error, but it just shows nothing into the form.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.Controls.Add(nuevoLabelCuenta);
```

(in the inner for loop)

Comment: It works, now its showing the first column, but i got an OutOfRangeException when i try to show all the columns of the data. Any help? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you should have placeholder for the Label like Bas B said.

```
private void CuentasDeUsuarioForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List <string> [] cuentas = db.Select("SELECT * FROM cuentas_de_usuario");
        foreach(List<string> acc in cuentas)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < acc.Count-1; i++)
            {
                Label nuevoLabelCuenta = new Label { Text = acc[i] };                        
                this.panel1.Controls.Add (nuevoLabelCuenta );
            }
        }
    }
```

where Panel1 is your placeholder

Comment: It works without the -1, but it shows one column and i want to show all of them (9 columns). Any help? Thanks again :-)

Comment: easiest way is to change your select statement into ("SELECT COL1+' '+COL2+' '+COL3" from cuentas_de_usuario")